# NullPointerException when generating RSA keys with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, rsa, nullpointerexception, bouncycastle

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RSAKeyPairGenerator rsaKeyPairGen = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = rsaKeyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
}
```

the `rsaKeyPairGen` is not null, but the `generateKeyPair()` method is throwing NullPointerException. What may be wrong?

Error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.RSAKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(Unknown Source)
at pkg.main(Main.java:154)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the bit length and the random number generator you want to use for the key (see the [javadoc](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/RSAKeyPairGenerator.html)):

For generating a 2048 bit RSA key:

```
rsaKeyPairGen.init( new KeyGenerationParameters( new SecureRandom(), 2048 ) );
```

Comment: almost there, your code is throwing:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.crypto.KeyGenerationParameters cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyGenerationParameters

Comment: and there is a lot of arguments to create a RSAKeyGenerationParameters.. I'll read about.

Comment: it works with KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC"); Thanks anyway.

Comment: But KeyPairGenerator is not a bouncy castle class. Any idea how to solve the cast exception without using it?